# Add custom styling rules to an even element from a list

Tags: html, css

So I have the following case:

> - First Element
> - Second
>     Element
> - Third Element
> - Forth Element
> - Fifth Element
> - Sixth Element
> - Eight
>     Element

I want to add a special rule only to odd elements from the list. The problem is that each element does not have it's specific class so I can apply the styling to them.
I tried something like this:
 `.class :even {color:white;}`

**EDIT** : Please don't appologize for breaking some rules, but learn the rules ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look here: http://www.webbykat.com/2013/01/styling-every-nth-element-css3-jquery-and-grid-view-templates

This is an example that might help you:

```
.class ul li:nth-child(2n) {color:white;}
```

Comment: .class ul li:nth-child(2n) {color:white;} - d instead of s :)

Comment: Is there a difference using `(2n)` and `(even)` ? What option is the best?

Comment: I would personally recommend `(2n)`, worked all the time for me

Comment: I tried to use `(n)` for the odd elements but it doesn't work. Can you tell me please what's the problem?

Comment: Try `(2n+1)`. Here is a css tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/ that will help you alot

Answer (score 1):

The selector is `:nth-child(even)`

And you might have a excess space character before the colon.